# Can I define my own local repository in Gradle

Tags: gradle, ivy

I want to define my own local repository in a gradle build script so that I can do something like this:

```
repositories {
    localIvy()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I want to be able to define my "localIvy" method with the url and patterns for this repository so that I can use the method in both the repositories and uploadArchives closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but you can do this:

```ruby
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository;

IvyArtifactRepository ivyLocal() {
    return uploadArchives.repositories.ivy({
        url "C:/Development/ivy"
    })
}
```

Within the closure there, you should be able to add any of the configuration stuff (patterns, etc) that are [available for ivy repositories](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3aivy_repositories).